# Trying to edit a reply when the button is clicked but this error pops out

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to edit my bot's reply but this error pops out:

> Error [INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.

Code:

```js
client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand){
        return
    }
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if(interaction.customId === 'EDIT'){
            interaction.editReply({
                content: "You clicked the button.",
                ephemeral: true
            })
        };
    }

    const { commandName, options } = interaction

    if (commandName == "button"){
        const AslashButton = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
            new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('EDIT')
            .setLabel('Button')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
            .setDisabled(false)
        );
        interaction.reply({
            content: "Button.",
            components: [AslashButton],
            ephemeral: true
        })
    };
})
```

I used `deferReply` but it replied 'TestB is thinking...'

How can I make the message deferred?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use **followUp** after you defer or reply to an interaction, and also, please check for the intents.

Comment: Where can I put **followUp**?

Comment: Also, I turned on all intents.

Comment: Never mind, I just figured it out.